# How to flip through pictures by swiping your figures across the screen in android?

Tags: android, android-image

Can someone please tell me how do I create the android phone style picture view in the gallery. That is, when you click on a picture, it pops up as a full screen and you can swipe your finger across the screen and flip through the other pictures in the folder.

How do you create that particular view?

Comment: That exactly are you trying to imitate? Because there is a Gallery Widget that may well do the majority of what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `ViewFlipper` to easily switch between different child views and you can use a `GestureDetector` to detect the swipe gesture.

Answer (score 0):

Override the gallery adapter with a base adapter which has this behavior.